# crawling google play reviews by selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to crawl the google play reviews, I found the review elements by xpath like this

```
List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='body-content']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]//div[@class='single-review']"));
```

Google play always gives me 40 elements, it bothers my paging process.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are collecting any specific app. reviews?

Comment: Share the url if possible.

Comment: @LittlePanda - I think I got him , he is trying to count app. review from playstore , For any particular app. I recently tried his code and that always returns 40 but in actual reviews are 40+ there..